# how do I using option tag to select the specific data from database with FLASK

Tags: html, sql, database, sqlite, flask

my data from database, and I can use "SELECT * FROM factors WHERE Crash_Year = 2001/2002/2003" to display specific data. but I don't know how to achieve this function in my html.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCU7T.png)

For example, if I select 2002, there are display the year of data are 2002.

I want to use option tag and here are my html coding:

```
{% block content %}
<article>
    <form action="/show/" method="post">
        <label for="year">Choose the rang of the Year:</label>

        <select id="year" name="year">
          <option value="2001">2001</option>
          <option value="2002">2002</option>
          <option value="2003">2003</option>
          <option value="2004">2004</option>
          <option value="2005">2005</option>
          <option value="2006">2006</option>
          <option value="2007">2007</option>
          <option value="2008">2008</option>
          <option value="2009">2009</option>
          <option value="2010">2010</option>
          <option value="2011">2011</option>
          <option value="2012">2012</option>
          <option value="2013">2013</option>
          <option value="2014">2014</option>
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Crash Year</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Crash Severity</th>
            <th>DrinkDriving</th>
            <th>Driver Speed</th>
            <th>Fatigued Driver</th>
            <th>Defective Vehicle</th>
            <th>Count Crashes</th>
            <th>Count Fatality</th>
            <th>Count Hospitalised</th>
            <th>Count Medically Treated</th>
            <th>Count Minor Injury</th>
            <th>Count All Casualties</th>
        </tr>
        {% for row in factorsinfo %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Crash_Year }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Crash_Police_Region }} </td>
            <td>{{ row.Crash_Severity }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Involving_Drink_Driving }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Involving_Driver_Speed }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Involving_Fatigued_Driver }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Involving_Defective_Vehicle }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Count_Crashes }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Count_Fatality }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Count_Hospitalised }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Count_Medically_Treated }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Count_Minor_Injury }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Count_All_Casualties }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

</article>

{% endblock %}
```

and here is my app.py:

```
@app.route("/show", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show():
    g.db = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    d = {}
    d['id'] = ""
    d['Crash_Year'] = ""
    d['Crash_Police_Region'] = ""
    d['Crash_Severity'] = ""
    d['Involving_Drink_Driving'] = ""
    d['Involving_Driver_Speed'] = ""
    d['Involving_Fatigued_Driver'] = ""
    d['Involving_Defective_Vehicle'] = ""
    d['Count_Crashes'] = ""
    d['Count_Fatality'] = ""
    d['Count_Hospitalised'] = ""
    d['Count_Medically_Treated'] = ""
    d['Count_Minor_Injury'] = ""
    d['Count_All_Casualties'] = ""
    factorsinfo = []
    cursor = None
    try:
        cursor = g.db.cursor()
        rows = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM factors ;')
        for row in rows:
            #print(row)
            d = {}  # necessary; weird ...
            d['id'] = row[0]
            d['Crash_Year'] = row[1]
            d['Crash_Police_Region'] = row[2]
            d['Crash_Severity'] = row[3]
            d['Involving_Drink_Driving'] = row[4]
            d['Involving_Driver_Speed'] = row[5]
            d['Involving_Fatigued_Driver'] = row[6]
            d['Involving_Defective_Vehicle'] = row[7]
            d['Count_Crashes'] = row[8]
            d['Count_Fatality'] = row[9]
            d['Count_Hospitalised'] = row[10]
            d['Count_Medically_Treated'] = row[11]
            d['Count_Minor_Injury'] = row[12]
            d['Count_All_Casualties'] = row[13]
            factorsinfo.append(d)
    except Exception as e:
        return """<h1> Error occurred when accessing the database</h1>
        <p>{}</p>""".format(e), 500

    if cursor:
        cursor.close()
    g.db.close()    
    return render_template('show.html', factorsinfo=factorsinfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem statement could be:

> If route is called from a POST request, and user has selected a
>   "year", only send that year's data to the html

One way to solve that would be to only send the selected year's data back to the html here
 `return render_template('show.html', factorsinfo=factorsinfo)`

Before the return, you will need a routine to collect and send the data from `factorsinfo` that  contains the selected year. You will need to use flask's [`request.method`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods) and [`request.form`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#the-request-object). In pseudo code:

- Is it a post request? (ie `request.method` == 'POST')
- Is a year selected? (ie `request.form['year'] is not None`)
- Find the data in `factorsinfo` for that year
- Return *that* set to the `render_template`

It *could* be done in the html, but the aforementioned `return` would have to also send the year that was selected, and an `if` clause would need to added after this `{% for row in factorsinfo %}` clause in the html.